# My minecraft keeps crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My Minecraft keeps crashing and it says at the end of the logs "Process crashed with exit code -532462766",

Comment: I don't think this is a Minecraft-specific error. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: i see you also attempted to post a ticket to the Mojang Jira website [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-161702) where it was shut down because you were using **1.8.9**. i'm going to ask the same thing the first person did: **does this crash happen in 1.14.4?** if so, **please include the full crash log here.** (edit: wrong link)